Canadian(?) kids' TV show in which an Arthurian knight is brought to the modern era
I distinctly remember, circa 2005-2009, seeing (parts of) a live-action TV show, almost certainly on YTV, in which a Knight of the Round Table is brought forward into the present day, and sees a trophy (possibly the Stanley Cup) on television, which he becomes convinced is the Holy Grail. The only kids' time-travel show I'm finding from the era is Timeblazers, but I remember this show being in a less documentary-like format (based on the handful of episodes uploaded to YouTube by one of the actors), more going for comedy.
This was almost certainly just the premise of a single episode. I remember there being some kind of time machine troubles. It may not have been on YTV, because I think I remember seeing it at some wealthier friends' house.

It sounds vaguely like "The Fisher King", but probably not, too many things not right.

Ah-ha! Once I realized that I might have seen it on Family, rather than YTV, I suddenly remembered the show Mentors. A quick couple searches later, and sure enough, it's Once and Future King (Season 4 Episode 10). As I thought, the series revolves around a time machine which brings (semi-) historical figures forward into the present, and it was indeed the Stanley Cup (even identified by name!) which gets taken for the Holy Grail. I was wrong about one thing, though: it was not an Arthurian knight, but rather King Arthur himself, who is brought to the modern era.
Given that I was too young to remember when the episode first aired, I must have seen it in reruns.
